# How to get column name for second largest row value in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, numpy, dataframe

I have a pretty simple question - I think - but it seems I can't wrap my head around this one. I am a beginner with Python and Pandas. I searched the forum but couldn't get a (recent) answer that fits my need.

I have a data frame such as this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.1, 2.7, 5.3], 'B': [2, 10, 9], 'C': [3.3, 5.4, 1.5], 'D': [4, 7, 15]}, index = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'])
```

Which gives:

```html
          A   B    C   D
    a1  1.1   2  3.3   4
    a2  2.7  10  5.4   7
    a3  5.3   9  1.5  15
```

**My question is simple : I would like to add a column that gives the column name of the *second* max value of each row.**

I have written a simple function which returns the second max value for each row

```
def get_second_best(x):
    return sorted(x)[-2]

df['value'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_second_best(row), axis=1)
```

Which gives:

```html
      A   B    C   D  value
a1  1.1   2  3.3   4    3.3
a2  2.7  10  5.4   7    7.0
a3  5.3   9  1.5  15    9.0
```

But I can't find how to display the column name in the 'value' column, instead of the value... I'm thinking about boolean indexing (comparing the 'value' column values with each row), but I haven't figured out how to do it.

To be clearer, I would like it to be:

```html
      A   B    C   D  value
a1  1.1   2  3.3   4    C
a2  2.7  10  5.4   7    D
a3  5.3   9  1.5  15    B
```

Any help (and explanation) appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One approach would be to pick out the two largest elements in each row using [`Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) and find the column corresponding to the smallest of those using [`Series.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html):

```
In [45]: df['value'] = df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).idxmin())

In [46]: df
Out[46]:
      A   B    C   D value
a1  1.1   2  3.3   4     C
a2  2.7  10  5.4   7     D
a3  5.3   9  1.5  15     B
```

It is worth noting that picking `Series.idxmin` over `DataFrame.idxmin` can make a difference performance-wise:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(100, 4)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
%timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).idxmin()) # 39.8 ms ± 2.66 ms
%timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2)).idxmin() # 53.6 ms ± 362 µs
```

Edit: Adding to @jpp's answer, if performance matters, you can gain a significant speed-up by using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), writing the code as if this were C and compiling it:

```
from numba import njit, prange

@njit
def arg_second_largest(arr):
    args = np.empty(len(arr), dtype=np.int_)
    for k in range(len(arr)):
        a = arr[k]
        second = np.NINF
        arg_second = 0
        first = np.NINF
        arg_first = 0
        for i in range(len(a)):
            x = a[i]
            if x >= first:
                second = first
                first = x
                arg_second = arg_first
                arg_first = i
            elif x >= second:
                second = x
                arg_second = i
        args[k] = arg_second
    return args
```

Let's compare the different solutions on two sets of data with shapes `(1000, 4)` and `(1000, 1000)` respectively:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(1000, 4)))
%timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).idxmin())     # 429 ms ± 5.1 ms
%timeit df.columns[df.values.argsort(1)[:, -2]]          # 94.7 µs ± 2.15 µs
%timeit df.columns[np.argpartition(df.values, -2)[:,-2]] # 101 µs ± 1.07 µs
%timeit df.columns[arg_second_largest(df.values)]        # 74.1 µs ± 775 ns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(1000, 1000)))
%timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).idxmin())     # 1.8 s ± 49.7 ms
%timeit df.columns[df.values.argsort(1)[:, -2]]          # 52.1 ms ± 1.44 ms
%timeit df.columns[np.argpartition(df.values, -2)[:,-2]] # 14.6 ms ± 145 µs
%timeit df.columns[arg_second_largest(df.values)]        # 1.11 ms ± 22.6 µs
```

In the last case, I was able to squeeze out a bit more and get the benchmark down to 852 µs by using `@njit(parallel=True)` and replacing the outer loop with `for k in prange(len(arr))`.

Comment: That's great, works like a charm ! Wish I thought about it myself. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 5):

Here's one solution using NumPy. The idea is to `argsort` the values in your dataframe, select the second last column, and finally use this to index `df.column`.

```
df['value'] = df.columns[df.values.argsort(1)[:, -2]]

print(df)

      A   B    C   D value
a1  1.1   2  3.3   4     C
a2  2.7  10  5.4   7     D
a3  5.3   9  1.5  15     B
```

You should find this more efficient than Pandas-based solutions:

```
# Python 3.6, NumPy 1.14.3, Pandas 0.23.0

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(100, 4)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

%timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).idxmin())  # 49.6 ms
%timeit df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2)).idxmin()  # 73.2 ms
%timeit df.columns[df.values.argsort(1)[:, -2]]       # 36.3 µs
```

Comment: +1; always nice to have a NumPy equivalent. It might be worth noting that if the data frame were much wider, then `df.columns[np.argpartition(df.values, -2)[:,-2]]` would become a possible alternative. For a `size=(100, 100)` data frame, the `argsort` based solution takes 364 µs, while `argpartition` takes that down to 168 µs.