# Python/Pandas: Finding index for the nlargest and keeping only those above a value

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to retrieve n column names corresponding to the set of columns where are the n largest values.
Then, these names are to be kept in a list, only if the value is above a given threshold.

As an example, given the three columns 'Paul', 'Eric', 'Marc', let say I want at most 2 column names, and threshold value is 0.5. I would then obtain the column 'Best' as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

start = '2020-01-01 00:00+00:00'
end = '2020-01-01 05:00+00:00'

pr1h = pd.period_range(start=start, end=end, freq='1h')
r = len(pr1h)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(r,3), index=pr1h, columns=['Paul', 'Marc', 'Eric'])
```

After processing:

```
df
                      Paul      Marc      Eric            Bests
2020-01-01 00:00  0.124974  0.525182  0.415339         ['Marc']
2020-01-01 01:00  0.991917  0.489479  0.668359 ['Paul', 'Eric']
2020-01-01 02:00  0.204156  0.610034  0.644715 ['Eric', 'Marc']
2020-01-01 03:00  0.385546  0.981641  0.089667         ['Marc']
2020-01-01 04:00  0.912330  0.711822  0.148064 ['Paul', 'Marc']
2020-01-01 05:00  0.301186  0.313572  0.323487               []
```

I could find on SO [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464947/how-to-get-column-name-for-second-largest-row-value-in-pandas-dataframe) that shows a way to get the index depending the rank of the value in a given row.
I guess it could be a starting point (maybe not optimized in terms of speed, because run several times, but it seems a good start.

I could then have:

```
df1['1st_largest'] = df.columns[df.values.argsort(1)[:,-1]]
df2['2nd_largest'] = df.columns[df.values.argsort(1)[:,-2]]
```

My array ought not to have more than 20 to 50 columns, so I kept with `argsort` instead of `argpartition`.

But now, I am stuck. I have no idea how to check that value related to one of these column is above 0.5 so that I can put it into the list.

Any help will be welcome, thanks!

Comment: Hello @r.ook, the expected output is the column 'Bests'. If you run the code, you will see it only gives you the 3 columns 'Paul', 'Marc', 'Eric'. Bests

Comment: Ah okay I misunderstood the question.  I think @QuangHoang got you covered then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to mask the dataframe with `where` and `stack`:

```
df['Bests'] = (df.where(df.gt(0.5))         # change 0.5 to your threshold
                 .stack().groupby(level=0)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).index
                                   .get_level_values(1).to_list()
                       )
              )
```

Output:

```
                      Paul      Marc      Eric         Bests
2020-01-01 00:00  0.124974  0.525182  0.415339        [Marc]
2020-01-01 01:00  0.991917  0.489479  0.668359  [Paul, Eric]
2020-01-01 02:00  0.204156  0.610034  0.644715  [Eric, Marc]
2020-01-01 03:00  0.385546  0.981641  0.089667        [Marc]
2020-01-01 04:00  0.912330  0.711822  0.148064  [Paul, Marc]
2020-01-01 05:00  0.301186  0.313572  0.323487           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I retained your solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as Quang, but using `GroupBy.agg(list)`:

```
dfg = df.where(df>0.5).stack().groupby(level=0).nlargest(2)
df['Bests'] = dfg.reset_index(level=2).groupby(level=0)['level_2'].agg(list)

                      Paul      Marc      Eric         Bests
2020-01-01 00:00  0.494089  0.500048  0.398106        [Marc]
2020-01-01 01:00  0.571067  0.896135  0.445951  [Marc, Paul]
2020-01-01 02:00  0.769473  0.830661  0.909551  [Eric, Marc]
2020-01-01 03:00  0.828074  0.025853  0.670196  [Paul, Eric]
2020-01-01 04:00  0.651157  0.641126  0.346411  [Paul, Marc]
2020-01-01 05:00  0.752359  0.970789  0.231323  [Marc, Paul]
```

Comment: Ramadan mubarak :)

Comment: @Erfan, thanks a lot for your help. I compared execution time of both solution, and this one does take twice more time than that of Quang unfortunately. Thanks nonetheless!